# Get original/source instance in __clone()

Tags: php, clone

Is there any possibility in php to get the original source instance/object inside `__clone` method?

Without saving `$this` or it's hash/id before.

I tried using `$this` and backtrace, but both return the new/cloned instance.

```
class Cl
{
    public function __clone() {
        var_dump(spl_object_id(debug_backtrace()[0]['object'])); // returns int(2)
        var_dump(spl_object_id($this)); // returns int(2)
        
        // how to get the original/source instance, ie. int(1), here?
    }
}


$cl = new Cl();
var_dump(spl_object_id($cl)); // returns int(1)
var_dump(spl_object_id(clone $cl)); // returns int(2)
```

Comment: _Once the cloning is complete, if a `__clone()` method is defined, then **the newly created object's `__clone()` method will be called**, to allow any necessary properties that need to be changed._.  So `$this` is the new cloned object.

Comment: Seems you can't do the way you want. What you can do is to add the instance to some class attribute like `$this->original = $this`, then in `__clone()` you can access the `$this->original`. Or you can delegate the clone to a different class which can access both objects (not using `clone $obj` though).

Comment: Did you give up?

Comment: no, I am thinking actually about PR to php-src as it seems there is no possibility for this currently in php without `$this` backup before cloning

Answer (score 1):

> Once the cloning is complete, if a `__clone()` method is defined, then **the newly created object's `__clone()` method will be called**, to allow any necessary properties that need to be changed.

As [Felippe Duarte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1580044/felippe-duarte) mentions, you can set the original object instance and use that:

```
class Cl
{
    //private $original;
    
    public function __construct() {
        $this->original = $this;
    }
    public function __clone() {
        var_dump(spl_object_id($this->original)); // returns int(1)
    }
}

$cl = new Cl();
var_dump(spl_object_id($cl)); // returns int(1)
var_dump(spl_object_id(clone $cl)); // returns int(2)
```